# How does Array.toList work in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm looking at this snippet:

```
val here: Array[Int] = rdd.collect()
println(here.toList)
```

... looking at the source for `toList` (on `TraversableOnce`) and `Array` (`Array` does not inherit `TraversableOnce` though), but I can't find the connection that will make Scala consider an `Array` as a `TraversableOnce` - if that is even what happens. Is there some implicit at work here? Is there a conversion via `ArraySeq` or `WrappedArray`? How does that `toList` work?

Comment: Thanks! I will read those.

Answer (score 4):

Array does not extend `TraversableOnce`, but it is implicitly convertible to `IndexedSeq`, which does!

This means that internally, the array is converted to a `WrappedArray`, then `toList` is called on this.

See here for more info:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html

Comment: Yes, it happens in the compiler.  This implicit conversion in particular is found in `Predef.scala`.